# Excel 2007 - Mandatory single cell input with unique value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am working in a call center and I create the daily reports of tickets.
The daily report contains the tickets(logged calls in the system) and the queue(language) they have been logged. Ex.: `"CALL12121/IM12121212 - IT/FR/EN/RO queue"`

The excel file looks sth like this:

...............A.......... |...............B................|..............C..............|

1  .....**Ticket Nr**   ....|....  **Language FR**.....|.....**Language IT**....|

2 ....IM123456......|..............1.................|..............................|

3.......................... |.................................|..............................|

So, what I need is, basically, when an agent completes the Excel report with the ticket number (e.g. `IM1213123`) he MUST enter a value for the queue and the value is the number `1`. After that all the queue/language cells for that row to be locked/blocked and that agent not to be able to enter other values.

For example: The excel sheet looks empty like the above one. The agent enters/copy-paste the ticket number in a cell in the column `TICKET` and after he needs to enter the queue/language value. And in case he doesn't enter a value for the queue something (a windows I guess) will prompt him, when he tries to add another value in any other cell(except the corresponding one), that he has completed the report correctly (or something like that)

Example: the column A is named `Ticket` column B is named `FR` and column C is named `IT`.
I am the agent and I need to complete my report and lets say I have a single ticket to report. I open the Excel Daily Report file -> Paste the ticket number in the A2 cell, and after that I complete also the language/queue column. Lets say I enter 1 in B2 for FR language. And if I also want to enter another 1 on C2 to show me an error or for the rest of the row to be blocked as I am not allow to enter multiple values for in the Language part in the report. I mean one ticket (IMxxxxx) can't be created on both FR and IT queue. Only 1 queue to be allowed to be 'selected'. Only for 1 language to be able to enter a value.

So as from the above example: for IM123456, I should only enter a single value, either 1 for FR, either 1 for IT, can't be both and if none is enter and I move on the next row or trying to save the file to receive a warning that some cell values have not be entered.
The same thing for that row and the same for the next one etc.
So basically for a ticket nr entered in a row, only one value to be entered on one of the language columns for that row.

I know that is part of Excel Macros and VB programming(where I have no knowledge) can you please give me the code or maybe where should I read more etc ?

I am working in Excel 2010.

Comment: You've obviously put a lot of work into writing this out so I won't vote to close until you've had a chance to increase the clarity of your question — as it stands I think that this question is not specific and possibly too specialised.

Comment: The usual approach would be to design a **UserForm** to facilitate data entry.............an *Event* macro could be written to supply the same restrictions.

Comment: @JustinJDavies Well I don't know how to put it more exactly, I still dont have the points to put up screenshots. For example for the language cells: Take it a Java Radio button: you only select/mark one radio option. In case you decide to change the radio option to a new one, after the new one was selected the previous was deselected. So this is kind of sums up my question: When an agent enters a cell value for the Language(EN or IT or FR etc.) he can enter a value for only one in that row.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Hmm maybe.. But do you know the steps? or some online tutorial or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dropdown list instead and just have one field called language

Check this out : http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html